# How to fix height/view port issue for spinner loader

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing issues with adding a spinner loader to a website. Here's the context:

So i have an issue, my company wants me to add a spinner loader for a website because there is a slider that will need the website to load all the images before turning it into a slider, but the images will be loaded one by one vertically before turning into a horizontal slider. That looks so displeasing and such i was task to add a spinner loader so that it will run while the background will load the images and will only disable the spinner once it is fully loaded. The first problem is the spinner is not displaying at the correct height, it is displayed at the most top of the page, i have set it to run at the center of the webpage but rather it will ran at the center of the top. The second problem is that i have disable the spinner but it keeps on spinning even though there is code set to disable the spinner.

Update code:The problem of spinner not disable has been fixed. The problem face now is still the spinner will not be create an overlay over the z-axis to be display. It first will appear on the most top left corner, then fixed when loading the page it will briefly appear at the center of the top page which should mean the height may have some issues, it seems that rather than an extra scene covering the web page at centering the spinner, it felt more like the spinner is adding its own section on top of the navbar and centering. So its sequence is somthing like appear on top left-> later center on center top -> then back to top left before disable it. Am using laravel. Any ideas on what my cause this issue?

Here's the HTML code for blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spinner Loader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="website-container">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
             <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Here's the CSS code for styles.css:

```
    `.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent black overlay */
    z-index: 999999; /* Ensure the overlay is on top of other content */
    align-items: center;
}

    /* Adjust the spinner size as needed */
    .spinner-border {
        width: 3rem;
        height: 3rem;
    }
`
```

And here's the JavaScript code for script.js:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    spinnerWrapperEl.style.display = 'none';
}, 200);

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    spinnerWrapperEl.style.opacity = '0';


});
```

[Here's a screenshot of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVhJZ.png)

[Screenshot of briefly working but not as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79bpV.png)

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue that the spinner wasn't centered in the viewport - https://jsfiddle.net/ue87gby0/

Comment: And the disappear on window load part, also appears to work fine with the code you have shown us - https://jsfiddle.net/buwhcgda/

Comment: Please ensure you provide enough code (and only enough) to *reproduce* the error.  As noted in comments above, the code provides does not demonstrate the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: The issue appears to be around `window.load` - this [fires when the *initial* content has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) - it will not fire if you load images later, I suggest you at least debug when the `load` event is firing (if at all)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for the inconsistency. First is it seems that i did not use the correct way to include the css. Now it seems to include it but there is a new issue where the code does not affect the spinner size.

```
.spinner-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); /* Semi-transparent black overlay */
    z-index: 999999; /* Ensure the overlay is on top of other content */
    align-items: center;
  }

  /* Spinner styles */
  .spinner-border {
    width: 60px; /* Adjust width as needed */
    height: 60px; /* Adjust height as needed */
    /* border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spin 1.2s linear infinite;  */
  }
```

This above is the CSS, i cant seem to know why the width and height will not affect the spinner.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<body>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->


        <div class="spinner-wrapper">
            <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </div>
         </div>


</body>

<script>
/*slick js to run client logo*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fade out the spinner overlay after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.spinner-wrapper').fadeOut();
    }, 2000);

    // Initialize the Slick slider
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Is there a reason why?